# What is the difference between breath and breathe? When to use breath and breathe?

Tags: word-usage

These two words really confuse me all the time even though I want to use them properly but I can't choose one cause I don't know when to use breath and breathe.

Comment: What did you find when you looked these words up in the dictionary and why didn’t that help you? If you edit your question to explain, we should be able to take it off hold.

Answer (score 4):

"Breath" is a **noun** and may refer to a complete cycle of breathing or the air we inhale or exhale.

"breathe" is a **verb** which refers to the process of inhaling and exhaling.